# ShellScript for Killing and Starting Program every 5hrs

Tags: linux, shell

I have a raspberry pi and I want to start a java application for 5 hours, kill it and start it again.

Because I need to login via SSH I thought it was clever to run the java application within screen (because I want to do other things while the program is running).

So without the script I started with:

```
screen -S java
java -jar program.jar
```

And then I send the Keys [CTRL] + [A] + [D] to detach.

Now I need to write this in shell.
I started with:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Check if app runs right now
OUTPUT="$(screen -ls)"
if [[ $OUTPUT == *"javaapp"* ]]
then
 #Say that the javaapp is currently running
  echo "javaapp is up!";
  #Kill the javaapp!
  screen -d javaapp #Does not work
fi
#Start it again
```

But it does not work :/
And I don't even know how to fix it since it's the first script I am trying to write. Is there anyone who can help me?

(Oh: And I would run the shellscript every 5hrs via. cronjob)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you just configure your operating system's process supervision system to restart the service whenever it's down? Then you just configure a kill every five hours, and let the automatic restart do its thing. Many of these will also automate signal delivery for you too (for instance, with runit, `sv force-restart your-service-name` will Do The Right Thing).

Comment: Related question: What *is* your operating system/distro? The distro and version will determine which process supervision system it ships with; may be upstart, systemd, traditional SysV init (which will automatically restart processes listed in /etc/inittab), or one of many others -- DJB's daemontools; runit; supervisor; launchd (on MacOS), etc etc etc.

Comment: Hello Charles!
Thanks for your answer. My distro is "raspbian" which is - according to different websites - a modified debian distro.

To your first suggestion: The service is not really down, but the java program does simply not work anymore. I'm not the developer of the java program thus I can't fix it...

Comment: `upstart` is definitely available as a package for raspbian, even if not included out-of-the-box for your version.

Comment: You could technically use `timeout` with an infinite `while` loop, though I'm not sure how robust that would be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this trick via cron:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -f /opt/javaapp.pid ]]
  kill -9 `cat /opt/javaapp.pid`
  rm /opt/javaapp.pid
fi

nohup java -jar program.jar > /opt/javaapp.log 2>&1&
echo $! > /opt/javaapp.pid
```

Edit: I'm not sure it works with java apps though, or with apps that tend to fork and spawn other processes. Watch out for zombies if you try this.

Also, if anybody knows a better way, please share it. Now I'm curious.

Comment: *At least* check that nothing else inherited the PID before killing it, or you can end up killing random processes that had the bad luck to end up in the wrong part of the PID table.

Comment: feel free to suggest an edit, this is just a working prototype that *needs* to be improved. It's a good idea, can you put it into the code above?

Comment: Even better, don't use a pidfile at all: `fuser -k app.lck; java -jar program.jar >app.log 3>app.lck` -- killing only programs with `app.lck` open. This will thus also work with apps that launch child processes, apps that self-daemonize, etc. as long as those children don't close FD 3.

Comment: I like this one better, thanks for sharing! Can you please spoon feed me and the other users visiting this and integrate it into the answer / provide a complete answer?

Comment: It's an improvement, yes; feel free to adopt it. I'm still staunchly against any approach other than using a process supervision system built for the purpose -- why in the world would you roll your own tool when there are folks who've put years into building special-purpose tools and fixing all the corner cases, and when those tools are already present in your distro?